# One-form current in 3d QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, conservation-laws, quantum-hall-effect, baryons

3d QED in IR can be described in terms of dual scalar field $\varphi$ have **trivially conserved current** with two indices, associated with U(1) one-form symmetry:

$$
J_{\mu\nu} = \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho}\partial^\rho \varphi
$$

In Komargodski paper [Baryons as Quantum Hall Droplets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09253) there are two statements about this current, which are unclear to me (you can find this statements in article before (2.4)):

> **It is conserved simply because the
>   space of $\varphi$ configurations is a circle and $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$.**

I dumbfounded by this statement, in my opinion conservation current doesn't related to any topology..

> **The charged objects are strings.**

I have one unsatisfactory argument for this: because string sweep 2d surface, we can simply integrate this current over 2d surface, and in such way define coupling of current to string.

I will be very appreciate for any answers!

Answer (score 2):

The conservation law $\partial^\mu J_{\mu\nu}=0$ would be a mere identity if $\varphi$ were a function, but it is not a function: it satisfies 
$$
 \varphi\simeq\varphi+2\pi.
\tag{1}
$$
The conservation law says that $\star J$, the one-form dual to the two-form $J$, is closed:
$$
d\star J=0.
\tag{2}
$$
However, this does *not* imply that $\star J$ is exact. The underlying manifold is topologically a circle, and the condition (1) means
$$
\oint \star J=2\pi
\tag{3}
$$
where the integral is around the circle. The conservation law (2) does imply 
$$
 \star J=d\varphi
\hskip1cm
 \text{locally},
\tag{4}
$$
where "localy" means on any topologically trivial segment of the circle, but not globally over the whole circle. The conservation law (2) can be regarded as a differential version of the integral equation (3), which is presumably what the author meant by "It is conserved simply because the space of $\varphi$ configurations is a circle."

Now consider the second quoted statement, which I'll repeat with some context:

> The charged objects are strings. On one side of the string $\varphi$ is at $0$ and on the other side it is at $2\pi$.

To construct the charge operator, we don't integrate the $2$-form current $J$ over a $2$-dimensional surface. Instead, we integrate its Hodge dual $\star J$, which is a one-form, over a 1-dimensional surface. The following paragraphs explain this in more detail.

The concept of a $p$-form symmetry is nicely reviewed in [Harlow and Ooguri](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05338). In $D$-dimensional spacetime, the current associated with a $p$-form symmetry is a $p+1$-form $J$. Its Hodge dual $\star J$ is a $D-p-1$-form, and the conservation law can be written in differential-form notation as $d\star J=0$. The form $\star J$ can be integrated over a $D-p-1$ dimensional submanifold to get an operator that implements the symmetry.  Ordinary local objects (which are associated with points, or $0$ dimensional submanifolds) are invariant/neutral under the symmetry (if $p\geq 1$), but an extended object corresponding to a submanifold $C$ that "wraps" around a compact dimension (for example) can be charged under the symmetry if $C$ and $\Sigma$ are linked (in the topological sense, like two rings that are linked together).

The most familiar case is $p=0$ (ordinary symmetry). Then the conserved current is a $1$-form, so $\star J$ is a $D-1$-form (which can be integrated over a Cauchy surface to obtain the charge operator), and the charged objects are particles. A $D-1$ dimensional submanifold can be "linked" with a $0$ dimensional submanifold (the particle's location in space) in the sense that, in spacetime, we can't deform one past the other without touching.

In the question, we have $D=3$ and $p=1$. The current $J$ is a $2$-form, and its Hodge dual is a $1$-form, which we can integrate it along any "string" ($1$-dimensional submanifold) to obtain the charge operator. The charged objects — the things that can be nontrivially linked with such a string — are *also* strings in this case. More precisely, they are strings in space, so they sweep out a 2-d surface in spacetime.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please provide details about "general recipe"?

Comment: @Nikita In the case of $p$-form symmetries with $p\geq 1$, I don't know a straightforward recipe for constructing the conserved current associated with the symmetry (maybe the paper's author does?), but we can go in the opposite direction: given the current, we can construct the charge operator as described in the answer. That operator is the infinitesimal generator of the symmetry, and once we have the generator, we can see what kind of extended objects it affects. (It doesn't affect local operators. I referred to $\varphi\to\varphi+2\pi$ as "the symmetry," but that was a sloppy short-cut.)